DLL load failed while importing cv2 in windows server 2012
I am trying to run python app using IIS Http handler mapping. On my local machine it is working fine.
On windows server 2012, I followed below steps to deploy app.

Copy app.py and requirement.txt file under one folder named as "prod"
Open CMD as admin, navigated to prod folder and create a virtual environment.
Executed command "pip install -r requirement.txt". I will write this file content also later.
All packages installed successfully.
Created a application in IIS and mapped a module. To get executable path run "wsfastcgi-enable"
Now go to IIS root and click on FastCGI settings and added two environment variable.
Run https://localhost or direct python ./app.py. Getting below error.


After this error, I have installed VC++ 2015, 2022 redistribute but same error.
Requirement.txt file have below content.

absl-py==2.1.0
astunparse==1.6.3
blinker==1.8.2
certifi==2024.7.4
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
contourpy==1.2.1
cycler==0.12.1
easyocr==1.7.1
editdistance==0.8.1
efficientnet==1.0.0
essential-generators==1.0
filelock==3.15.4
Flask==3.0.3
flatbuffers==24.3.25
fonttools==4.53.1
fsspec==2024.6.1
gast==0.6.0
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.65.0
h5py==3.11.0
idna==3.7
imageio==2.34.2
imgaug==0.4.0
intel-openmp==2021.4.0
itsdangerous==2.2.0
Jinja2==3.1.4
keras==3.4.1
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
keras-ocr==0.9.3
kiwisolver==1.4.5
lazy_loader==0.4
libclang==18.1.1
Markdown==3.6
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
matplotlib==3.9.1
mdurl==0.1.2
mkl==2021.4.0
ml-dtypes==0.3.2
mpmath==1.3.0
namex==0.0.8
networkx==3.3
ninja==1.11.1.1
numpy==1.26.4
opencv-python==4.10.0.84
opencv-python-headless==4.10.0.84
opt-einsum==3.3.0
optree==0.12.1
packaging==24.1
pillow==10.4.0
protobuf==4.25.3
pyclipper==1.3.0.post5
Pygments==2.18.0
pyparsing==3.1.2
python-bidi==0.4.2
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
PyYAML==6.0.1
requests==2.32.3
rich==13.7.1
scikit-image==0.24.0
scipy==1.14.0
shapely==2.0.4
six==1.16.0
sympy==1.13.0
tbb==2021.13.0
tensorboard==2.16.2
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
tensorflow==2.16.2
tensorflow-intel==2.16.2
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.31.0
termcolor==2.4.0
tifffile==2024.7.2
torch==2.3.1
torchvision==0.18.1
tqdm==4.66.4
typing_extensions==4.12.2
urllib3==2.2.2
validators==0.32.0
Werkzeug==3.0.3
wfastcgi==3.0.0
wrapt==1.16.0

My app.py content is below.

